# Simple table filtering with RXJS and Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am trying to have filterable table.
I have ListComponent like this:

```
export class CompanyListComponent implements OnInit {
  companies$: Observable<Company[]>;
  private searchTerms = new Subject<string>();

  constructor(private companyService: CompanyService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.companies$ = this.searchTerms.pipe(
        // wait 300ms after each keystroke before considering the term
        debounceTime(300),

        // ignore new term if same as previous term
        distinctUntilChanged(),

        // switch to new search observable each time the term changes
        switchMap((term: string) => this.companyService.searchCompanies(term)),
    );
}

search(term: string): void {
    this.searchTerms.next(term);
}
```

And my html looks like that:

```
<input #searchBox type="text" class="form-control" id="search-box" (keyup)="search(searchBox.value)">

<table class="table">
  <tr *ngFor="let company of companies$ | async">
    <td>{{company.name}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

When I am writing inside the search input, table is filtered as it should be. But when I refresh page there is no data in the table at all. It appears after I put something in the input. What should I do to get all table data when the page is loaded? I tried to just start search in ngOnInit but those tries went to nowhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the chain to be initialized when you subscribe to it you can use `startWith`.

```
this.companies$ = this.searchTerms.pipe(
  debounceTime(...),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  startWith(''),
  switchMap(...)
);
```

Comment: I don't know what it means

Comment: Shouldn't start with come first in the pipe?

Comment: Sorry, I was just going to write your answer too and I was building an example which I have linked

Comment: @ExplosionPills you should combine all the answers into a single answer.

Answer (score 2):

Change `searchTerms` to a `ReplaySubject(1)` and emit a default value in the constructor.

```
   private searchTerms = new ReplaySubject<string>(1);

   constructor(private companyService: CompanyService) { 
          this.searchTerms.next('');
   }
```

When the page refreshes the `searchTerms` does not emit a value until the user presses a key. This means that the `companies$` does nothing until the first search term is emitted.

Using a replay subject allows you to set what the first value will be.

Comment: Why `ReplaySubject` over `BehaviorSubject` in this case?

Comment: @ExplosionPills that works too, and would be less code.